# How to use string as a variable in class passing string as a parameter

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In have reusable I have used variable

```java
WebElement yellow = Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#yel"))

public void color(String color) { //something
}
```

Now in my main class if I call below method:

```
cls.color("yellow")
```

color method should use yellow webelement.

Since I have n number of color types, I don't want to use `if` condition in color method.

May I know how to use a string variable to identify the corresponding webelement.
Also I don't want to declare webelement as public.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do what you do for the `yellow` field at lot more times for other colors, and you need to look them up by CSS selector, then I suggest you use a `Map`, and that you use a loop to look them all up.

```
private Map<String, WebElement> colors = new HashMap<>();
{
    final String[] COLOR_MAPS = {
            "#yel", "yellow",
            "#red", "red",
            "#grn", "green" };
    for (int i = 0; i < COLOR_MAPS.length; i += 2)
        colors.put(COLOR_MAPS[i + 1], Driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(COLOR_MAPS[i])));
}
```

```
public void color(String color) {
    WebElement elem = colors.get(color);
    if (elem == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown color: " + color);
    ...
}
```